# When $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures, what kind of measures are $\mu \wedge \nu$ and $\mu \vee \nu$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I've recently encountered the notations $\mu \wedge \nu$ and $\mu \vee \nu$ for measures $\mu, \nu$ in the book "Random measures, theory and applications" by Kallenberg. I'm not sure what they represent but it must be some standard notation because as far as i can tell he doesn't define them. Here is the context (this is lemma 1.31 in the book):

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be locally finite measures on a Borel space $S$ and fix a differentiation basis $\mathcal I$ for $\mu \vee \nu$. Then as $ I \rightarrow \{s \}$ along $\mathcal I$, we have
$$
||\hat\mu_{I}-\hat\nu_{I} || \rightarrow 0, s \in S \text{ } a.e. \mu \wedge \nu.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a compact metric space it follows that the space $C_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ is a Banach lattice, where it follows easily that $C_{\mathbb{R}}(X)^*$ is also a Banach lattice under the ordering $L_1\geqslant L_2\Leftrightarrow (L_1-L_2)(f)\geqslant 0$ for all $f\geqslant 0$. However $C_{\mathbb{R}}(X)^*$ is isomorphic to the space of Radon signed measures $\mathcal{M}(X)$ in $X$. Then $\mu \wedge \nu$ defines the glb and $\mu \vee \nu$ the lub of $\mu,\nu\in \mathcal{M}(X)$.

It can be shown that

$$
\mu \vee \nu=\mu+(\nu-\mu)_+\quad \text{ and that }\quad \mu \wedge \nu =-((-\mu )\vee (-\nu ))
$$

where $\lambda _+$ is the positive part of the signed measure $\lambda $.